# Dependent Variable with Multiple Survey Questions

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I am attempting to create a dependent variable that considers 4 survey questions all of which have dictomous outputs. However, I am unsure what would be the best practice for doing this.
Is creating an index score variable the best practice or is there more accurate?

Nothing, currently cleaning data at the moment from a survey questionaire.
Dataset contains over 2K observations.
I am just thinking ahead and how to get the best effects possible from a logit model with this type of dependent variable.

Comment: You can create a ```data.table``` with two columns - 1. Questions (character type) 2. Answers (boolean type)

Comment: I think you'll have better luck on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) as this is really a question about what statistical method is appropriate, rather than it is a question about how to code it in R.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. You'll receive more effective help if you do so. Also, what hypotheses did you declare before you collected the data? How do these hypotheses relate to the four dependent variables?